# How to customize django DateRangeFilter

Tags: django, filter, date-range

I would like to change the date options of the django-filters' DateRangeFilter. I have tried a custom class which overrides the original init, but I get the error "TypeError at /member_contact_filtered/: lambda() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)" and don't understand where the problem is. This is what I have:

```
class CustomDateRangeFilter(django_filters.DateRangeFilter):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    try: 
        options = kwargs.pop('options') 
        self.options = options 
    except KeyError: 
        pass
    kwargs['choices'] = [(key, value[0]) for key, value in self.options.iteritems()] 
    super(CustomDateRangeFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class MemberContactFilter(FilterSet):

from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

options = {
'': (_('Any Date'), lambda name: Q()),
1: (_('Today'), lambda name: Q(**{
    '%s__year' % name: datetime.today().year,
    '%s__month' % name: datetime.today().month,
    '%s__day' % name: datetime.today().day
})),
2: (_('Past 7 days'), lambda name: Q(**{
    '%s__gte' % name: (datetime.today() - timedelta(days=7)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
    '%s__lt' % name: (datetime.today()+timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
})),
}

next_contact_date = CustomDateRangeFilter(label='Follow up', options=options)

class Meta:
    model = MemberContact
    fields = ['next_contact_date']
```

Answer (score 0):

The filters.py I was using was different than the one I was looking at on github. Oh well.